# Two bits of two __m128i to four bits of one __m128i -SSE

Tags: c, sse, bit

I have two variables __m128i (a and b) and I am only interested on the bit63 and bit127.

Finally, I want a variable __m128i (c) with the four bits of the variables a and b on the bit31, bit 63, bit 95 and bit 127.

In conclusion (pseudocode):

```
c.bit31  = a.bit63
c.bit63  = a.bit127
c.bit95  = b.bit63
c.bit127 = b.bit127
```

If I use a store(float array), cast to int array[4], and finally a load(int array), I will lose a lot of time.

I don't know how I could do it using intrinsecs operations (SSEx x <= 4.2).

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Post some code. If you want alternatives, make sure we understand your problem first.

Comment: And why can't you simply do `c = (((a>>63)&1)<<31)|(((a>>127)&1)<<63)|(((b>>63)&1)<<95)|(((b>>127)&1)<<127)`?

Comment: Now that you added that last statement there (the one in bold) - intrinsic operations are HW-specific, i.e., for each processor, the designated compiler provides a unique set of these operations. So what processor are you using? If possible, then please look it up on the web first (using your favorite search-engine), and then add a list of those intrinsic operations as part of your question.

Comment: I'm using SSEx | x <= 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using only SSE2 like this

```
__m128i t1 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(a,0xd0); //0xd0 = 3100 in base 4
__m128i t2 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(b,0xd0); //0xd0 = 3100 in base 4
__m128i t3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(t1,t2);
__m128i t4 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(t3,0xd8); //0xd8 = 3120 in base 4
__m128i t5 = _mm_and_si128(t4,_mm_set1_epi32(0x8000000));
```

Here is a working example

```
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    __m128i a = _mm_setr_epi32(1,-2,3,-4);
    __m128i b = _mm_setr_epi32(5,-6,7,-8);

    __m128i t1 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(a,0xd0); //0xd0 = 3100 in base 4
    __m128i t2 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(b,0xd0); //0xd0 = 3100 in base 4
    __m128i t3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(t1,t2);
    __m128i t4 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(t3,0xd8); //0xd8 = 3120 in base 4
    __m128i t5 = _mm_and_si128(t4,_mm_set1_epi32(0x8000000));  
    int x[4];
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)x,t5);
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) printf("%x ", x[i]); printf("\n");
}
```